# Is there any way i can get the bounds(north-east and south-west) of the map view on bounds/center/view area change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, maps, tomtom

I'm using TomTom Map SDK in NextJs to create functionality such that when map is loaded based on the map bounds, i query all the nearby restaurants in that area. And on map zoom or drag event i want to call the api again with new bounds to update the restaurants list.

Here's my component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import * as tt from "@tomtom-international/web-sdk-maps";
import "@tomtom-international/web-sdk-maps/dist/maps.css";

function Map() {
  const mapElement = useRef();
  const [map, setMap] = useState({});
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(21.112869);
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(51.504);

  useEffect(() => {
    let map = tt.map({
      key: "MY_MAP_KEY",
      container: mapElement.current,
      stylesVisibility: {
        trafficIncidents: true,
        trafficFlow: true,
      },
      center: [longitude, latitude],
      zoom: 14,
    });

    console.log(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat);

    const addMarker = () => {
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = `Hello There!`;
      const size = 50;
      const popup = new tt.Popup({
        closeButton: false,
        offset: size / 2,
        anchor: "bottom",
      }).setDOMContent(div);

      const marker = new tt.Marker()
        .setLngLat([longitude, latitude])
        .setPopup(popup)
        .addTo(map);
    };

    addMarker();

    return () => map.remove();
  }, [longitude, latitude]);

  return (
    <>
      {map && (
         <div ref={mapElement} className="map" />
      )}
    </>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

I can across this but it doesn't work! Not sure if such event exists.

```
   window.addEventListener("ns-bridge-ready", function (e) {
      var nsWebViewBridge = e.detail || window.nsWebViewBridge;
      map.on("dragend", function () {
        console.log(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat, "nj");
        // let center = map.getCenter();
        // nsWebViewBridge.emit("mapCenterChanged",
        //   center.lng.toFixed(3) + ", " + center.lat.toFixed(3));
      });
    });

    window.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
      console.log(e, "jfdsf");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright just found the solution. For anyone struggling with the same, You can just use map.on("dragend", callbackFunc) directly inside useEffect and that would call the function everytime there's a drag event end. The best solution that worked for me is using "moveend"

```
map.on("moveend", () => {
console.log(map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat, map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng);  });
```